# Trying to print 20 lines from a word document using python docx module, but it is only printing the first line

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to print 20 lines from a word document using python docx module, but it is giving not more than the first line.

This is my code

```
import docx
filename='TableOfContents.docx'
doc = docx.Document(filename)
for i in range(20):
    print (doc.paragraphs[i].text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('TableOfContents.docx')
x = 0
for i in doc.paragraphs:
    if x < 20:
        print(i.text)
    else:
        break;
    x = x + 1
```

Comment: Hey Alex thanks for your interest. That has given me the error  'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Paragraph' and 'int' '

Comment: So I've added x as a counter which counts what paragraph you are on

Comment: How is the document structured?

Comment: Ah document is not structured as paragraphs, it is line by line